# converting string to NSDate issue: [__NSDate Length] unrecognized selected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdateformatter

`indexNumber.row` is a date like `2012-03-09 23:00:00 +0000`. I've tried a handful of different ways to get my date into an `NSDate`, but I keep getting the title error.

```
NSString *inputString = [self.measurements objectAtIndex:indexNumber.row];

// Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:inputString ];
NSLog(@"date format is: %@", date);
```

Any ideas why I get the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDate length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6ca0c60'

Comment: What error do you get, could you be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You get that error because you are passing a `NSDate` object to `dateFromString:`.

Add an `NSLog` and you will see that:

```
NSString *inputString = [self.measurements objectAtIndex:indexNumber.row];
if ([inputString isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]]) {
    NSLog(@"inputString is of type NSDate");
}
```

Also, here is how to reproduce your error:

```
NSString *inputString = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:inputString];
```

That means that the array `self.measurements` contains `NSDate` objects and not `NSString` objects.

---

When you correct your current problem, you will probably encounter a new one because you don't use the correct date format. To parse date strings of type: `2012-03-09 23:00:00 +0000` you should use the following date format:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zz"];
```

Comment: i've tried a few different setDateformats. I get the same error with the above format: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDate length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6ca0c60'"

Comment: added an NSLog after setting the string and get "date format is:2012-03-09 09:36:53 +0000"

Comment: nailed it.  after running your if, it was in fact an NSDate and no conversion was necessary.  thanks sch.

Answer (score 0):

Either do as *sch* suggests, or if you don't need the time at all, you can just truncate the string you feed to your dateFormatter. E.g. like so:

```
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[inputString substringToIndex:9]];
```

Where *9* is an index, up to which you want to take a chunk of string.

Comment: That won't solve his problem. If the problem was the date formatting, he would get a `nil` date and not the error he mentioned.

Comment: If the problem is in the difference between date format and the format of given string - it **will** solve the problem. If the string is *nil*, then of course it won't give anything, as well as you suggestion.