# NSDate is read as NSDate and NSCFString

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, ios-simulator, nsdate

My backend is Parse.com. I have users with an array of `NSDate` objects as the timestamp in which they completed certain actions.

I am trying to read the last object in that array to test whether it was completed during the first 3 hours of the day.

The weird issue I am having is the following. On my physical device, I load the array of the supposed `NSDate` objects and both log to the console the object and class of object. I get the following:

```
OBJECT: 2016-01-19T01:09:18.239Z
CLASS: __NSCFString
```

Since it is not an `NSDate` object, I use a formatter to make it one and make my calculation. No crashes so far.

When I run the same code on the simulator, I get the following:

```
OBJECT: 2016-01-20 05:50:34 +0000
CLASS: __NSDate
```

So the app crashes (as it should) because I am trying to, with a formatter, to make an already `NSDate` object into an `NSDate` from a string which it isn't. The crash logs show the following:

```
-[__NSDate length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffcf3f9c480
```

So I thought maybe the objects are actually different. I go to Parse.com and copy the objects. They are the same:

```
["2015-12-20T17:47:38.134Z"]
["2016-01-20T05:50:34.253Z"]
```

I know I could just check whether it's `NSCFString` or `NSDate` and handle them accordingly but I'm curious to know what the issue is. Any help is appreciated. Been at it all day. Cheers.

EDIT: After running it a few more times on my physical device. Some objects will show as `NSCFString`, others `NSDate`. Checked Parse.com again to make sure all objects were the same and again, true.

```
["2016-01-20T06:07:41.435Z"]

["2016-01-20T06:07:39.454Z"]

["2016-01-20T04:53:53.419Z"]
```

Comment: you can use isKindOfClass to check if object is nsstring or nsdate and accordingly.

Comment: I think you first check is value is NSDate object? for this here is the link which helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9637407/3378413

Comment: Can you look at this answer and see if this helps. I think the object they are sending is custom parse object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33329932/how-to-query-and-convert-parse-com-date-to-nsdate-string

Comment: Are you accessing the date from a PFObject or a PFObject subclass?

Comment: @kRiZ from `PFObject`

Answer (score 0):

here two methods that can helps you to handle this kind of issue. the first one return a NSDate object and the second one return string date format. you can use one of them or both.

```
- (NSDate*) getDateFromObject:(id) object{
if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]]) {
    return (NSDate*)object;
}
else if ([object isKindOfClass:NSString.class]){
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:object];

    return date;
}
// return nil otherwise
return nil;
}

- (NSString*) getStringFromObject:(id) object{
if ([object isKindOfClass:NSString.class]) {
    return (NSString*)object;
}
else if ([object isKindOfClass:NSDate.class]){
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:object];

    return dateString;
}
// return nil otherwise
return nil;
```

}

Comment: "I know I could just check whether it's NSCFString or NSDate and handle them accordingly but I'm curious to know what the issue is." Thank you either way, will use your code :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue here. My case is that i'm receiving a JSON object data and serialising it to the object which have NSDate value .. For this, all you need is to use little manual coding to pass the text as NSDate rather than normal string from the web service:

Example (showing error):

```
- (void)userFromJson:(NSData *)object error:(NSError **)error {
    NSError *localError = nil;
    NSDictionary *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:object options:0 error:&localError];

    if (localError != nil) {
        *error = localError;
        return;
    }

    for (NSDictionary *keyDict in parsedObject) {
        for (NSString *key in keyDict) {
            if ([self respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(key)]) {
                [self setValue:[keyDict valueForKey:key];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Correct one:

```
- (void)userFromJson:(NSData *)object error:(NSError **)error {
    NSError *localError = nil;
    NSDictionary *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:object options:0 error:&localError];

    if (localError != nil) {
        *error = localError;
        return;
    }

    for (NSDictionary *keyDict in parsedObject) {
        for (NSString *key in keyDict) {
            if ([self respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(key)]) {
                if ([key isEqualToString:@"dateOfBirth"]) {
                    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];
                    NSDate *d = [df dateFromString:[keyDict valueForKey:key]];
                    [self setValue:d forKey:key];
                }
                else {
                    [self setValue:[keyDict valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works for me now, but i'm trying to find a way in order NOT TO hardcode possible variable names (you know ... modular coding).

Hope this helps you.

EDIT:
After little work I came to the following solution:

In your relevant class you have to `#import <objc/runtime.h>` ... and then you can check for the local object parameter type and act accordingly:

```
- (void)userFromJson:(NSData *)object error:(NSError **)error {
    NSError *localError = nil;
    NSDictionary *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:object options:0 error:&localError];

    if (localError != nil) {
        *error = localError;
        return;
    }

    for (NSDictionary *keyDict in parsedObject) {
        for (NSString *key in keyDict) {
            if ([self respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(key)]) {

                objc_property_t property = class_getProperty([self class], [key UTF8String]);

                if ([[self getClassOfProperty:property] isSubclassOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
                    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:[keyDict valueForKey:key]];
                    if ([scanner scanFloat:NULL]) {
                        [self setValue:@([[keyDict valueForKey:key] floatValue]) forKey:key];
                    }
                    else if ([scanner scanInt:NULL]) {
                        [self setValue:@([[keyDict valueForKey:key] integerValue]) forKey:key];
                    }
                    else {

                    }
                }
                else if ([[self getClassOfProperty:property] isSubclassOfClass:[NSDate class]]) {
                    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                    NSString *stDate = (NSString *)[keyDict valueForKey:key];
                    if ([stDate length] == 10) {
                        [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
                    }
                    else {
                        [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
                    }

                    NSDate *d = [df dateFromString:stDate];
                    [self setValue:d forKey:key];
                }
                else if ([[self getClassOfProperty:property] isSubclassOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
                    [self setValue:[keyDict valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
                }
                else if ([[self getClassOfProperty:property] isSubclassOfClass:[NSData class]]) {
                    [self setValue:[NSData dataWithBytes:[[keyDict valueForKey:key] UTF8String] length:[[keyDict valueForKey:key] length]]
                         forKey:key];
                }
                else {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

-(Class)getClassOfProperty:(objc_property_t)property {
    NSString *objType = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getAttributes(property)];
    NSUInteger start =  [objType rangeOfString:@"\""].location;
    NSUInteger end =  [objType rangeOfString:@"\","].location;
    NSRange range;
    range.location = start + 1;
    range.length = end - range.location;
    NSString *objType2 = [objType substringWithRange:range];

    return [NSClassFromString(objType2) class];
}
```

Now to be more generic, instead of using specific format, you can use `NSDataDetector`, refer to http://www.techanswering.com/question/show/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again